# Should I make my iPhone app backward compatible with iOS 5?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

iOS 6 was launched recently and it includes some nice features like [SLComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). However, I hesitate to break backward compatibility with iOS 5. Are there any stats on how many people have updated to the latest iOS version? I was unable to find figures published by Apple. When will it be advisable to use features specific to iOS 6?

**UPDATE:** I found iOS adoption stats from a company called Chitika: http://insights.chitika.com/2012/ios-by-device/. As of 10/1/2012, 60% of iPhone users have iOS 6. Unfortunately, this looks like a static article rather than a page with continuously updated figures, but one can assume using a bit of extrapolation that iOS 5 still (as of 10/8/2012) represents a large chunk of users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple will probably never tell you, but here is a study using mobile ad impressions coming out of the Chitika Ad network which shows 60% of iPhones have been updated 2 weeks after the release of iOS6 (for the North American market):

http://insights.chitika.com/2012/ios-by-device/

Data from Chartboost suggests slightly lower adoption rates:

http://techcrunch.com/2012/10/05/after-early-boom-new-numbers-suggest-ios-6-adoption-may-be-reaching-a-plateau/

Mainly I guess due to fear of losing google maps and not getting that much in return (for older devices).  Probably a good idea then not to target iOS6 specifically...

Answer (score 0):

You can use iOS 6.0 features today, millions of users have upgraded their iDevices to the latest version (a lot of them even without knowing they did, it is all so easy these days).

But, there are many millions of users who either don't want to upgrade or can not upgrade because their device does not support iOS 6.0, so you should think really hard before leaving those users out in the cold.

If you have come up with an app idea that solely relies on iOS 6.0 features, then by all means go for it. If not, give users from 5.0 and higher the standard feature set and enhance this for those who adopted iOS 6.0 by asking at runtime what is there and what not.